# displaying image from database in android show into imageview

Tags: android

Hi In my application i have one login form based on username display all the data in edittext same like that in database I have all the details with image.All the data display correctly and image not displaying for that I used this url

```
http://domainname/xxxxxxx/folder/a.jpg
```

But above image is displaying correctly But I want based on username I want to display which image is in database I want to display that image

can any one help me

```
String picture1= json.getString("picture");
                     studentpic1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                        String image_url = "http://xxxxx/xxx/xxxx/".concat(picture1);
                        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, 0, studentpic1);
```

Comment: Have you not store user image with other information on same table ?

Comment: same table I am saving all the data with user images

Comment: So send username to server via http post and at server side get this user name and select image url and send it as resopnse. then parse the response data and display the image from the url in the image view !! simple !! :)

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont directly save the image in the db.Store its path and at the time of retriving display the imaging via parsing the path

Comment: saving all the images in folder same like that I did but url How to mention that one I don't no

Comment: If u saving the path in the db then u can easily get the file from the path

Comment: Not path directly image saving in database

Comment: In database a.jpg like this image I want to display that image in android imageview

Comment: thats what i am saying get the path of a.jpg and store it in the data base.While displaying the image in the imageView get that path from the database and parse it and show in the image view

Comment: like that I did I created one folder In that it will save all the images and storing in database only like this imagename.jpg now how to mention that one I am asking

Comment: small doubt from json I am getting that name of the image and in url I wrote like this http://domainname/mainfolder/subfolder/".concat(String.valueOf(picture1))

Answer (score 0):

Please get the exact path and do something like this

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will helps you [Click here](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/10/insert-and-retrieve-image-into-db.html)

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if(btnretrive==arg0)
    {
            String[] col={"image"};
            c=db.query("tableimage", col, null, null, null, null, null);

            if(c!=null){
                c.moveToFirst();
                do{
                    img=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image"));
                   }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            Bitmap b1=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);

             imageview.setImageBitmap(b1);
             Toast.makeText(this, "Retrive successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```